# I need an explanation to a for loop

Tags: c

I'm having problems explaining this code and I would really like a detailed explanation of how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int x=-3, y=0, k,j;

  for( k=j=-3 ; x= x+(k<j),++j ; y+=2);
  printf("x=%d  y=%d k=%d  j=%d",x,y,k,j);

  getch();
}
```

By the way, the answers are `x=-1 y=4 k=-3 j=0`. The problem is that I have tried Explaining it and I don't actually know how to get past the increment part (`++j`).

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: is this code even working in the first place? It needs to work first before it can be explained.

Comment: yes, it is working but i cant explain the prosses and that's what i need

Comment: Write it open as a while loop, and it will become easier to undestand.

Comment: Also, look up "C comma operator".

Comment: TBH anybody writing a loop with that kind of condition should be taken out and shot. That being said, try to perform syntactical transformations on that loop (transform it to a `while` loop, reorganize expressions, ...).

Comment: x=-1  y=4 k=-3  j=0 Because as for loop has semicolon all the processes in for loop happens first then the next line will be executed!

Comment: I'll try to change the loop and try it using the while statements but the root of the question is to derive the answer from this specific for loop. cos this was given in a written exam a few years back and I was going through the questions for my coming exams. so, in a written exam i wount be able to change it i just have to produce the answers

Comment: @HyeladiBassi: "in a written exam i wount be able to change it i just have to produce the answers" to produce the answers to this kind of borked loop it's usually necessary to perform these transformations, exactly as you need to perform incremental transformations to resolve a mathematical expression or equation. It's not changing the text of the problem, it's a tool to help you transform it to equivalent but more tractable code, which will lead you to your answer. I'm my answer I did exactly that, I didn't have any shortcut to arrive to the output values skipping those steps.

Comment: @MatteoItalia; thanks now I understand, it basically means I would have to convert it myself while solving to get my answers.

Comment: Exactly; it's like a mathematical expression, really. You have to apply some transformations allowed by the rules to get step by step nearer to something that you can trivially solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x=-3, y=0, k,j;
for( k=j=-3 ; x= x+(k<j),++j ; y+=2);
```

---

```
int x=-3, y=0, k=-3, j=-3;
while(x = x+(k<j), ++j) {
    y += 2;
}
```

---

```
int x=-3, y=0, k=-3, j=-3;
x += k<j;
while(++j) {
    y += 2;
    x += k<j;
}
```

---

```
int x=-3, y=0, k=-3, j=-3;
x += 0;
while(++j) {
    y += 2;
    x += k<j;
}
```

---

```
int x=-3, y=0, k=-3, j=-3;
while(++j) {
    y += 2;
    x += k<j;
}
```

Now, this is way easier to understand:

- at the end, `j` will be zero, as it's the exit condition of the loop;
- the loop will run twice, as the third time `++j` is evaluated it will evaluate to zero;
- `y` will end as 4, as it starts at zero, the loop runs twice and each time it's incremented by 2;
- `k` is never touched, so it stays at -3;
- in the loop body, `k<j` always, as they start equal but `j` has already been incremented once the control flow reach `x+=k<j`, so this statement becomes `++x`. As it runs twice, `x` becomes -1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes it a lot easier to understand